# paying for several items using PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

Is it possible to show a list of items the user is going to pay for (like from the cart) using new PayPal Mobile SDK, or there can be only a single position with costs summed up?
I don't see anything like this in the current code, but it's always better to ask. Same for shipping costs.

Any info when this would be added? (assuming it's not available atm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Brent from the card.io / PayPal Mobile SDK team here)

It is not possible to show cart-like item lists or shipping costs in the current versions of the PayPal iOS and Android SDKs (1.1.1 and 1.0.3 respectively). We do not have any information about when such a feature might be added.

Your app can display itemized purchase information *before* presenting the PayPal SDK UI to collect payment. If this approach does not work for your use case, please file an issue on the GitHub repo (either [iOS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues) or [Android](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues)) and our team will take a closer look.

Thanks for your question. Hope this helps.